# Jquery getJSON not returning large volume of data

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I'm running through the getJSON javascript jquery (1.8.3) command to call a routine MCV C #. The routine in C # returns the data, however I can not obtain them in return getJson. This does not happen if I limit the amount of data returned. 
Does anyone know if it is problem of limitation of bytes transferred?

Follows the code I'm using:

### JQuery

```
function fnPesquisar(posCli) {      
   $.getJSON('/DiarioOficial/ConferenciaPesquisa()', fnPesquisarCallback);      
   return false;
}


function fnPesquisarCallback(json) {       
   $(json).each(function () {
        //...
   });             
}
```

### C#

```
public JsonResult ConferenciaPesquisa()
{          
      BWF.DiarioOficial.Publicacao bwf = new BWF.DiarioOficial.Publicacao();
      return Json(bwf.Pesquisar(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Short answer: reduce the amount of data you are transferring. Seriously though, why do you need to transfer so much data in one go? Can you not page through it?

Comment: Is not possible because the client need to see all data for purposes of analysis and comparison between them ... Changing by a paging toranará unfeasible to analyze the User.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is for your `GET` request, try to change limitation of your GET requests by changing server setting, maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request) helps you.
Also you can change limitation of Json object by this line in your `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>
```

Or simply, change your method to `POST`.